# how to to host single-spa root-config and modules on a central server during development

Tags: localstack, single-spa

I've been experimenting with single-spa for a while, and understand the basics of the developer experience. Create a parcel, yarn start on a unique port, add the reference to the import map declaration, and so on. The challenge with this is that as my root-config accrues more and more modules managing ports and import-maps starts to get tedious. What I want is to publish these modules to a central repository and load them from there (e.g., http://someserver.com/repository/moduleA/myorg-modulea.js, etc.).

I was recently introduced to localstack and started thinking maybe a local S3 bucket would serve for this. I have a configuration where builds (yarn build) are automatically published to an s3 bucket running on localstack.  But when I try to load the root config index.html from the bucket I get the following JS error:

```
Unable to resolve bare specifier '@myorg/root-config'
```

I can access the JS files for each parcel and the root-config just fine via curl, so I suppose this would be a problem with any http server used in the same way. I can flip the root config to use the standard webpack-dev-server instead (on port 9000) and it works okay. So I'm guessing there's a difference between how a production build resolves these modules vs. the local build.

Has anyone tried something like this and got it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue that I got to work with `http-server` by adding each child .js file to a sub-folder in the root-config directory and launching the web server at the root-config directory level.

```
"imports": {
    "@myorg/root-config": "http://someserver.com/root-config.js",
    "@myorg/moduleA": "http://someserver.com/modules/moduleA/myorg-modulea.js",
    "@myorg/moduleB": "http://someserver.com/modules/moduleB/myorg-moduleb.js",
    "@myorg/moduleC": "http://someserver.com/modules/moduleC/myorg-modulec.js",
}
```

Note: By default, Single-SPA has an "isLocal" check before the current import mappings. You'll need to remove this if using a production build or it won't load the correct mappings.

```
<% if (isLocal) { %>
```

In my case, I was using localhost instead of someserver so I could navigate into the 'repository' folder and run `npx http-server` to get everything to run correctly.

I was hung up on this for a little while so hopefully this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  You and I went along the same journey and arrived pretty much in the same place.  I'm using terraform to set up the infrastructure in AWS but the net result is pretty much the same.

Comment: Is this directory structure only for deployed builds, or are you able to run this way from localhost too? We're looking for a way to run the root-config (with layout) _and_ the content apps from localhost behind a single port (monorepo, basically)... but we're webpack and JS-framework n00bs, unfortunately.

Comment: @McGuireV10 This will work with localhost as well. I got it to work by putting each child app's js files in a subfolder within the root-config directory, updating the import-map in index.ejs to accurately reflect paths, and running http-server in the root-config directory. This should host the root-config project and allow it to find the static js files.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, after trying several approaches to hosting a repository as described above, I found the unresolved bare specifier problem went away.  So I have to chalk that up as just not having the right URL in the import map.  Measure twice, cut once.